# Custom aggregation function in Sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

Is it possible (and how) to make custom aggregation in SQLite? I need to transform query which normally returns rows like

```
aaa | 12 | ...
bbb | 45 | ...
```

but should return now something like

```
aaa=12, bbb=45 | ...
```

i.e. to "aggregate" rows with some custom concatenation. So, is it possible even to concatenate columns of rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `group_concat()`:

```
select group_concat(col1 || '=' || col2, ', ')
```